# Not able to get html from URL with page query

Tags: java, html, url, jsoup

I'm trying to get an html document of a specific from a URL with a page number query in it ("https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/?p=181"). However, when I print out the result html, it always gives me the very first page.

Here's the snippet:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/?p=181").get();
Element e = doc.body();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/").data​("p", "181").get();
Element e = doc.body();
```

because i can see [here in the documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) that there is a method `data` used to set request parameters

Turns out it was the Website that has a problem/strange behavior, it's been solved doing two request to the endpoint and adding the session cookie of the first one inside the second one

Comment: Still getting the same result

Comment: @JanH are you sure? sorry if i ask, how are you "checking" that the page you are getting is or is not the first one?

Comment: @JanH if you use incognito mode on chrome, and you load "https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/?p=181" you will get the first page, than if you reload it, you will see the empty page... i think that there is a problem on the website, not on your code

Comment: I see, I suppose there isn't a way to programmatically simulate the reload process?

Comment: @Berto99 is right. there is no page with number 181. I think when you try to open the link for the first time, the webpage is somehow not able to get the 181st page(because it doesn't exist). But because of your first visit on the website, it shows you the first page because the webpage doesn't want to send you a empty page. There are 4486 results on the webpage and results are grouped by 25. 4486 / 25 = 179.xx. you can reach => https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/?p=180 as the latest

Comment: I tried the same thing with a link to 5th page and it did the same thing, had to reload to get the actual page. The result html is also an html of the first page again.

Comment: @JanH ok, i'll try to find why is this happening, give me some minutes

Comment: No, I'll give it a try

Comment: @JanH ok try to do a "Jsoup.connect("https://hudebnibazar.cz/kytary/110000/").data​("p", "181").get();"  and then the code i've posted

Comment: @Berto99 Nope, still gives me the first page :/

Comment: i've checked the documentation, and there is no "reload", after data try to set the session cookie to the session cookie of the first request

Comment: @Berto99 Using the previous cookies for the next request did the job. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @JanH no problem, i'll add to the answer this part, so that maybe can solve problem of future visitors